# MongoDB search string by first letter of each word

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongo schema as follows.

```
var employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 id: { type: String,ref:'Users' },
 FirstName: { type: String },
 LastName: { type: String },
 Skills: [
    {
        Category: { type: String },
        Level: { type: String }
    }
 ]}, { strict: true });
```

After Entering data it looks like this.

```
{
id: '123456',
FirstName: "Name",
LastName: "Last Name",
Skills: [
    {
        Category: "Traffic Management Supervisor ",
        Level: "Intermediate"
    }
]
```

}

**My problem i want to filter employers by his skill category. And i want to filter employees by first  letter of each word instead of entering whole string**

Ex: I need to filter all employees by  their skill category using **TMS**  instead of **Traffic Management Supervisor**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex match in the aggregate method. I would suggest that should you create those searches dynamically. Whatever input is and push them into $or and regex...

```
// Only filter by category field
Employee.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "Skills.Category": {
            $regex: '[tms]+',
            $options: 'i'
        }
    }

}])

// Any category match
Employee.aggregate([{
    $match: {

        $or: [{
            "Skills.Category": {
                $regex: '[tms]+',
                $options: 'i'
            }
        }, {
            "Skills.Level": {
                $regex: '[tms]+',
                $options: 'i'
            }
        }]

    }

}])
```

Comment: Hi @Semih Gk.  this  works fine. Thanks lot for your time.

Comment: Glad to help ;)